# How to use jquery-datepicker for date range

Tags: yii, jquery-ui-datepicker

Can someone tell me how to use the jquery-datepicker for a date range in yii? I got it to work for a single date how do i modify it to get a multiple dates.
I am new to yii framework.

Answer (score 8):

Try This For Example:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'model'=>$model, 'attribute'=>'birthday',
    'options'=>array(
        'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
        'yearRange'=>'-70:+0',
        'changeYear'=>'true',
        'changeMonth'=>'true',
    ),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'options'=>array(
 'showAnim'=>'fold',
 'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
 'changeMonth'=>true,
 'changeYear'=>true,
 'yearRange'=>'-100:+0',
 'defaultDate'=>'+0'
),
```

Comment: Give some explanation/background on your code. This is just a bunch of code

Comment: What does this add beyond @jamband's answer?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the solution to do it with CJuiDatePicker. Instead, I used the following in my view file:

```
<?php
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCoreScript( 'jquery.ui' );
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(
    Yii::app()->clientScript->getCoreScriptUrl().
    '/jui/css/base/jquery-ui.css'
);
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('daterangescript',"
    var dates = $('#ReportForm_date_start, #ReportForm_date_end').datepicker({
        defaultDate: '+1w',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == 'ReportForm_date_start' ? 'minDate' : 'maxDate',
                instance = $( this ).data( 'datepicker' );
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( 'option', option, date );
        }
    });

    $('#ReportForm_date_start, #ReportForm_date_end').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
",CClientScript::POS_READY);
?>
```

Don't forget to replace `ReportForm_date_start` and `ReportForm_date_end` to your own element ids.

Answer (score 1):

Yii CJuiDatePicker: Date Range

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
    'name'=>'datepicker-min-max',    
    'value'=>date('d-m-Y'),
    'options'=>array(        
        'showButtonPanel'=>true,
        'minDate'=>-5,
        'maxDate'=>"+1M +5D",
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'style'=>''
    ),
));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range) documentation to learn how to create date range.

After reading jQuery UI docs you should understand how does it works. Then you can use [CJuiDatePicker](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiDatePicker) widget to generate what you need.

It's not hard to adjust Yii widgets to your needs, I'd rather say it's very simple and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the clue you were looking for:

> a date range has 2 dates, one at either end

Presuming you know how to use `datepicker` widget to retrieve a single date from the user, the simplest approach would be to just instantiate 2 datepickers in your view and use the 2 dates sent back to your controller as the edges of the date range in your model.

Answer (score 0):

you can add 'yearRange' on the option.
you can fill it with 'start date:end date', example 'yearRange'=>'2008:2018',
or, how many years before and after this present year, write the code using - and +, example 'yearRange'=>'-8:+8', it means that 8 years before this years and 8 years after this years.

Answer (score 0):

```
From: <input type="text" name="date_from" id="date_from" />        
To: <input type="text" name="date_to" id="date_to" />


    <?php
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
           'name' => 'date_from',
           // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
           'options' => array(
               'showAnim' => "slideDown",
               'changeMonth' => true,
               'numberOfMonths' => 1,
               'showOn' => "button",
               'buttonImageOnly' => false,
               'dateFormat' => "yy-mm-dd",
               'showButtonPanel' => true,
               'onClose' => 'js:function(selectedDate) { $("#date_to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate); }',            
           )
       ));
       $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
           'name' => 'date_to',
           // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
           'options' => array(
               'showAnim' => "slideDown",
               'changeMonth' => true,
               'numberOfMonths' => 1,
               'showOn' => "button",
               'buttonImageOnly' => false,
               'dateFormat' => "yy-mm-dd",
               'showButtonPanel' => true,
               'onClose' => 'js:function(selectedDate) { $("#date_from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate); }',
           )
       ));
?>
```

Tutorial: http://wimarbueno.blogspot.com/2014/04/Yii-CJuiDatePicker-rango-de-fechas-en-datepicker-de-jQuery-UI.html